# jquery fancy box iframe zoom

Tags: jquery

I’m using Jquery Fancy Box plug in. I am starting fancy box on page load opening up a Iframe  (75% width and height). Is there a way to incorporate a zoom function or somthing like it so the web page opened in the iframe always fits?

```
$("#various5, #various6").fancybox({
'width' : '75%',
'height'    : '75%',
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it has to be the iframe to handle with usable width...

Comment: You can't do what you want... But the iframe target can know its width/height and scla to fit these values.